# Room возвращает null в ответ на запрос

Tags: android, kotlin, room

Есть ДАО

```
@Dao
interface CurrencyDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun save(currency: CurrencyEntity)
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun saveAll(currencies: List<CurrencyEntity>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM currencyEntity")
    fun loadAll(): LiveData<List<CurrencyEntity>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM currencyEntity WHERE name LIKE :value")
    fun findByNameOrCharCode(value: String): LiveData<List<CurrencyEntity>>
}
```

Я через репозиторий вызываю его методы в viewModel.

```
class CurrencyRepository(private val database: CurrencyDataBase) {
    val currencies:LiveData<List<CurrencyEntity>> = database.currencyDao.loadAll()

    suspend fun refreshCurrency() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val networkCurrencies = CurrencyApi.retrofitService.getValCurs().valList?.let {
                NetworkCurrencyContainer(
                    it
                )
            }
            networkCurrencies?.let { database.currencyDao.saveAll(it.asDatabaseModel()) }
        }
    }

    fun searchCurrency(value: String): LiveData<List<CurrencyEntity>> {
        return database.currencyDao.findByNameOrCharCode(value)
    }
}

class CurrencyListViewModel(applicationContext: Application) : ViewModel() {
    private val database = getDatabase(applicationContext)
    private val repository = CurrencyRepository(database)

    var currencies = repository.currencies

    fun searchCurrency(value: String) {
        val res = repository.searchCurrency(value)
            currencies= res
        Timber.v("${res.toString()} ${res.value.toString()}")
        Timber.v("${currencies.toString()} ${currencies.value.toString()}")
    }
}
```

О на вызов метода searchCurrency в моём viewmodel я получаю все время null от Room. Не могу понять почему. Метод searchCurrencu(value: String) у viewModel вызываю в фрагменте

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_currency_list, menu)
        val searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.tool_bar_search).actionView as SearchView
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                viewModel.searchCurrency(newText)
                return false
            }
        })
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
```

Хочу через ViewSearch в ToolBar реализовать поиск по БД. Но не могу получить данные по запросу. Хотя изначально данные получаю, когда мой репозиторий обращается к DAO посредством метода LoadAll. Но метод findByNameOrCharCode упрямо отказывается возвращать данные. При чем я пробовал вызывать вместо findByNameOrCharCode метод loadAll, что бы проверить, что он вернет и тоже получаю null. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отказался от LiveData в CurrencyDao в пользу списка.

```
@Dao
interface CurrencyDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun save(currency: CurrencyEntity)
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun saveAll(currencies: List<CurrencyEntity>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM currencyEntity")
    suspend fun loadAll(): List<CurrencyEntity>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM currencyEntity WHERE name LIKE :value || '%' OR charCode LIKE :value || '%'")
    suspend fun findByNameOrCharCode(value: String): List<CurrencyEntity>
}
```